# How to merge categories table with items table and returtn array of each category with items

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have three tables and after each table is the defined eloquent relationship of each entity.

**categories**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cars |
| 2 | bikes |

```
 public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(AccountItem::class, "category_item", "category_id", "item_id");
    }
```

**category_items**

| id | category_id | item_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

**items**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | volks |
| 2 | bmw |

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, "category_items", "item_id", "category_id");
    }
```

I am stuck on how to get a function that will return an array of the data with each category and the corresponding items. Incase the category has null items it returns a empty array of the category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your relationship is correct. If so, you can do this to load.

```
$categories = Category::with('items')->get();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $categoryArray = [
        'id' => $category->id,
        'name' => $category->name,
        'items' => $category->items->toArray()
    ];
}
```

Comment: thanks @Abdulla Nilam have declared empty array and looped while pushing the data to array. It has worked.